# I was trying to create a new user with create_user but its not working

Tags: django-views, django-forms, django-templates

This is a registration page function

```
def  register(request):
if request.method=="POST":
    username= request.POST['username']
    email= request.POST['email']
    password= request.POST['password']
    password2= request.POST['password2']
    if password == password2:
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            messages.info(request,'Email Already Used')
            return redirect('register')
        elif User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():    
            messages.info(request,'Username Already Used')
            return redirect('register')
        else:
            user=User.objects.create_user(username=username,email=email,password=password2)  #create_user not working
            user.save()
            return redirect('login')
    else:
      messages.info(request,'password not same')      
      return redirect('register')  
else:          
    return render(request,'register.html')
```

this is the register.html file

```html
<h1>SIGN UP HERE</h1>
<style>
    h5 {
        color: red
    }
</style>
{% for message in massages %}
<h5>{{message}}</h5>
{% endfor %}
<form method="POST" action="register">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>Username(admission number):</p>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <P>Email</P>
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <p>Password:</p>
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <p>Repeat password</p>
    <input type="password" name="password2" /><br>
    <input type="submit" />

</form>
```

I have imported User model for create_user method
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
but its not working

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want to create a function-based view for User creation. A much simpler way to do this is to build a [class-based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/intro/) using django's User model:

```
from users.models import User
from .forms import RegisterForm
from django.views import generic

class UserRegistration(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = RegisterForm
    template_name = 'register.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

In your forms.py file (in whichever app you are creating the users) you add the RegisterForm:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

`username`, `password1`, and `password2` are already built in fields for django Users, so it's already done for you.

Then in your `register.html` file all you need is to add the from:

```
<h1>SIGN UP HERE</h1>
<style>
    h5 {
        color: red
    }
</style>
{% for message in massages %}
<h5>{{message}}</h5>
{% endfor %}
<form method="POST" action="register">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
</form>
```

`{{form.as_p}}` renders all the fields in the order they appear in in your RegisterForm.